# Copying Excel ranges to Outlook mail: The method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get an error while copying Excel ranges from the worksheet through the userform and pasting to Outlook.

Error 4605 appears stating that the document is locked for editing.

I get this error the first time but after the first it comes and goes. When I click on debug it takes me to one of the page editor line items.

```
Private Sub Quoteiso9001_Click() 
    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim newEmail As Object
    Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object
    
    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    With newEmail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Sheet1.Range("C6").Text
        .Body = "Dear Valued Client" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "On behalf of SGS, we are delighted to provide you with an Estimate of Investment for ISO 9001:2015 Third Party Certification." & vbCrLf & "To meet your certification needs, I have enclosed an estimate of investment and timing for your review and consideration."
        .display
        
        Sheet1.Range("A8:G30").Copy
        
        Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
        Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
               
        pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
        pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
        pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        .display
        
        
        Set pageEditor = Nothing
        Set xInspect = Nothing
    End With
    
    Set newEmail = Nothing
    Set outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `pageEditor` section with code below

```
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.body)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
.display
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
.Send
```

Comment: It will be more helpful, if also post some explanation why, your code should work and why authors code doesn't work.